# Can not understand the usage of set(var val ${var}) in cmake

Tags: cmake

i have been learned cmake for a while. i got a puzzle about this piece of code:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
```

can someone help me figure out what's the meaning of ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} at the end of this code.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing 
`set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH my/path ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})`

You prepend to the list CMAKE_MODULE_PATH a path where CMake will seek for a Find.cmake or module-config.cmake (actually the path submitted is your_source_directory + /cmake

You can also write it like this : 
`set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH my/path;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})`

as in CMake, everything is a string and a list is simply strings separated with ';'

reference of the var itself (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html?highlight=cmake_module_path)

This variable is used by CMake internally when looking for a package (using find_package macro)

You can find the list of paths searched by cmake in the reference of find_package macro (here : https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/find_package.html?highlight=cmake_module_path)

Hope this answer correctly to you question.

Answer (score 0):

In this you are pre-pending the `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake` before the current `$CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`

Answer (score 0):

It is a concatenation. You are inserting the new value in the beginning of the list `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.